# WebPage printing issue

Tags: javascript, web, ionic-framework, printing

i have long web page, I want to make it printable when user use the default browser print function.

Currently I can print it as PDF, but it only print a part of the web page and the output is 1 page of PDF ( while the content of the web page has at least 2 pages ).

Is there anything I can do in the developer side ( for user I think there are some external tools help print the entire web site ) to allow user print the entire page easily.

I am using angularjs + ionicFramework

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp). You can include in your `index.html` something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

When the user will try to print the page your css rules in `print.css` will be applied.

Comment: i have this, so i can hide something i dont need in print mode, but it cannot print the entire page. i think the issue is about ionic framework.